# Django ORM call manager method from another manager?

Tags: python, django

Any tips on how I should be accessing other manager methods from within Manager.py?

No matter what I do, I can't seem to access my other manager's method.  Python complains that it isn't defined...

Is it going to cause problems if I import models inside of managers.py?  Circular includes or whatever?

managers.py:

```
# Returns the whole family who are active
def get_active_dependents_including_guardian( self, consumer, connectedOnly = False ):
    logger.debug('get_active_dependents_including_guardian')
    results = self.model.objects.filter( guardian = consumer,
                                      is_active = True ).order_by('dob')

    if connectedOnly:
        from myir import models
        #OPTIMIZE: this can be optimized if I query for all patient ids for each dependent in one trip.  But I don't even know how to do this yet cause I'm a noob.
        results = [d for d in results if models.DependentPatientID.objects.get_patient_ids(d)[0].patient_id_integer == 0] **#HERE IS PROBLEM**

    return results

# some stuff omitted...
# this is the manager of models.DependentPatientId
class DependentPatientIDManager( models.Manager ):
    def get_patient_ids(self, dependent ):
        dpid = self.model.objects.get( dependent = dependent.id )
        return dpid
```

Comment: Try this: `from myir import models as myir_models` and use `myir_models`. Or, `from myir.models import DependentPatientID`

Comment: Maybe a little progress...  Now error is: 'DependentPatientID' object does not support indexing.  Just to be clear, I have no idea what this error means.

Comment: Actually, after I answered, I realized, that code after `if connectedOnly:` does nothing useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change:

```
from myir import models
```

to

```
from myir.models import DependentPatientID
```

The reason being, you might have already done `from django.db import models` and the names are conflicting.

Now,

```
class DependentPatientIDManager( models.Manager ):
    def get_patient_ids(self, dependent ):
        dpid = self.model.objects.get( dependent = dependent.id )
        return dpid
```

returns an object, and not a queryset. So, `DependentPatientID.objects.get_patient_ids(d)[0]` would fail.

So try this

```
if connectedOnly:
    from myir.models import DependentPatientID
    patient_id_integer = 0
    dep_patient_id = DependentPatientID.objects.get_patient_ids(d) 
    if dep_patient_id:
        patient_id_integer = dep_patient_id.patient_id_integer
        results = [d for d in results if patient_id_integer == 0]

        #Or just

        if not patient_id_integer:
            results = []
```

Comment: This is good stuff, thank you.  One last question...  patient_id_integer is a NULLable int.  How do I test for IS_NULL rather than "== 0".

Comment: Check the edit. You could just do `if not patient_id_integer`